# Is it possible to play HTTP Live video on a browser? 2012

Tags: html, http, http-streaming

I was wondering if it is possible to stream to the user HTTP Live video. NOT a video file.
LIVE video. Using any technology. Flash or HTML5. I did some research and most of the players I found support live streaming but most of them mean youtube-like style streaming, where you can click further in the video and get the video loading. I am talking about LIVE video, happening the same time the user watches the video.

I got the incoming HTTP packets, stored in a file called "current_frame.h264". This files gets updated as the packets come in. It does NOT grow in size, just get updated. (stays at around 17-20kb). Now I want to take this file and show it on a browser. Anybody can help me out?

Comment: YouTube already does live video

Answer (score 0):

Apple developed something like that a while ago: https://developer.apple.com/streaming/

All you need is a webserver and a HTML5 enabled webpage.

With this technology you also have the ability to stream different quality files based on the connection (mobile usage for example)

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html